# Error in unity when trying to build ios app

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've been getting this error when I try to build my ios app in unity.

Assets/Scripts/UIController.cs(33,17): error CS0103: The name `PlayGamesController' does not exist in the current context

PlayGamesController.cs exists however the error still shows in the console.

Comment: We're going to need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your PlayGamesController.cs lay in Editor subfolder. If so then move it to your game code.
For more details on special folders follow [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html).